# Alternative where I do not have to pass image as object

Tags: html, angular, lazy-loading, loading

I was implementing lazy loading the following way

file.html
 `<img class="image-example" [lazyLoad]="image0" />`

file.ts
`image0 = '../../../../assets/images/about/example.png';`

Is there a way where I can directly pass the path for lazy loading without making it an object in the "ts" file.
Ps Don't recommend loading="lazy", it does not do the work

Answer (score 0):

`img` src path start with `/`, this means root of static server folder

image0 = '/assets/images/about/example.png'